# How do I add a marker to the coordinate found with geolocate.trigger()?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I want to add a "marker" to the location I find with mapbox geolocate and drag and drop the user's own location

How can I do that?

My Code is :

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
      center: [34.1108604, 38.8837679],
      zoom: 7 
    });
    const geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
      positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          timeout : 10000
      },
      fitBoundsOptions: {
        maxZoom: 17
      },
      trackUserLocation: false,
      showUserLocation: false
    });
    map.addControl(geolocate);
    map.on('load', () => {
      geolocate.trigger();
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="map" style={Style}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!